# {pay / give} compliment

Tags: word-choice, politeness

Many times people use **pay** and **give** interchangeably with the **compliment**. Could you please tell me which one is correct?

> He paid her a compliment.

or

> He gave her a compliment.

Answer (score 2):

[pay compliment](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pay+compliment) is an idiom and **pay** is used in the sense of **to give** someone a compliment, consequently, both examples are correct in that they convey the same idea.

Another way to express it would be:

> He complimented her.

The last example uses **compliment** as a verb.

Answer (score 1):

Both are **correct** and understandable to mean he said something **favourable** or **nice** about her.